# Where is 'open in terminal'?

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to figure out where is 'open in terminal' when right clicking inside a folder? 
Last time I used it was in Ubuntu 10.10 and since upgrading have no luck with it.
I gave up on Unity and using Gnome but still can't find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you need install a package named [nautilus-open-terminal [image: Install nautilus-open-terminal]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-open-terminal):

[image: Install via the software center]

or:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

and restart nautilus:

```
nautilus -q && sleep 1 && nautilus -n
```

or logout and login again.