# How to set default terminal to tilda or yakuake when using "Open in terminal" from folder

Tags: command-line, nautilus, gnome-terminal

When I am inside folder in nautilus I want to be able to open that folder in terminal. This can be done with `nautilus-open-terminal` package described in [Where is 'open in terminal'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154414/where-is-open-in-terminal)

However, I use `tilda` as my default terminal, because it is drop-down which makes it easy to use.

So my question is - how do I use "Open in terminal" option to open new tab in `tilda` instead of default terminal?

This question is about opening terminal from folder, not about opening folder from terminal. Opening folder from terminal is easy - you just need to type `nautilus .` or `xdg-open.`

**EDIT:** Since nothing else worked, I solved this problem by writing nautilus script that outputs current location to text file and then another script (executed from my chosen terminal) that reads that file and uses `cd` to change directory.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/70540/how-can-i-set-default-terminal-used

Comment: @thnee Thanks for hint. However, it is not duplicate. Using ``gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'tilda'`` will cause terminal to open when using CTRL+ALT+T shortcut, but ``Open in terminal`` in nautilus still opens regular terminal instead of tilda

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/76712/setting-nautilus-open-terminal-to-launch-terminator-rather-than-gnome-terminal/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Have you tried this?

https://askubuntu.com/a/76747/164073

Comment: Tilda is not on this list. Anyway, I have tried all 5 options that were there and folder still opens in default terminal.