# Is there a quick way to open command window

Tags: command-line

Is there a quick way to open command window from file explorer? There is a shortcut in Windows 8 like "Open commmand window here".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes indeed, just install nautilus-open-terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

Then, log out and log back in and you'll have a new option when you right-click in any nautilus directory.

Comment: For some reason, I always have TWO entries...

Comment: Only drawback to this nautilus extension is that it can not be set to open terminal like tilda (http://askubuntu.com/questions/354890/how-to-set-default-terminal-to-tilda-or-yakuake-when-using-open-in-terminal-fr). But apart from that it works great.

Comment: That context menu is standard in xfce.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open a terminal window from anywhere using
Ctrl+Alt+t
on the keyboard.

Comment: It doesn't opens a terminal from my current directory but main directory.

Comment: I like Guake. It does a Quake-like drop down terminal using F12, but it opens at / and not at the current directory.