# How to open in terminal directory in opened in the most current nautilius window?

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal

I am looking for a command that, when called in terminal, will *cd* to the directory that is open in the most current nautilus widows.

On Mac, I use `cdf` provided with `zprezto/oh-my-zsh` that wraps OSX commands. It makes moving between `Finder` and `terminal` so easy and natural.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/154414/85695)?

Comment: No, I do not want to *right click*, I want to write *cdn* in my terminal to open a directory that is opened in nautilus.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt that is possible. You would have to export the directory nautilus is looking at as an environmental variable. Finder is much more integrated into OSX than nautilus is in Unity so I'm not sure that would be possible without hacking nautilus's code. Won't this do as a workaround?

Comment: The only problem I see is finding last window. Script can open context menu and call a custom action from it, I think.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to use `cdf` command to switch current directory in terminal to the one used in last nautilus window? It is to be used as a single command and not in syntax?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a single command.